# How can I use SCCM to audit installed displays

Tags: sccm, system-center

I want to see a list of the model numbers of all the monitors attached to the computers in my firm.  Is there an SCCM Query that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, it's under

`Attribute Class: Desktop Monitor`

`Attribute: Description`

I had to create a Join on the System Resources/Desktop Monitor ResourceID to get the System Resources Name attribute to tell which computers the monitors are connected to